# How to overlay Radiance (Top-of Atmospheric radiance) over Digital Numbers Image?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, envi, erdas-imagine

I am trying to process INSAT-3D images, which contain six different bands. I have to extract each and every band form the .h5 data file, so when I extract first band (MIR) band form the data set, I found that My MIR band image size is (3062, 3207) which digital number ranges form 0 to 1023, while its radiance size is (1, 1024) which ranges form 0 to 0.3. Can anyone please tell me how could I overlay these radiance values onto my image.

Comment: Use extract subset (Data management)

Comment: Can you expand on this to provide some information?